# Separate definition of inner class and enclosing class

Tags: c++, header-files, inner-classes, circular-dependency, code-separation

What is the proper way to separate the definition of an inner class and an enclosing class into different header files, if the enclosing class has a member variable which is an instance of the inner class?

Here is the header of `Outer` (the enclosing class):

```
//outer.h
#ifndef OUTER_H_INCLUDED
#define OUTER_H_INCLUDED

#include "inner.h"

class Outer
{
    class Inner;

public:
    /* public member functions */

private:        
    Inner inner_instance;
};

#endif
```

And the header of `Inner`:

```
//inner.h
#ifndef INNER_H_INCLUDED
#define INNER_H_INCLUDED

#include "outer.h"

class Outer::Inner
{
    /* definition */
};

#endif
```

This won't compile. The problem is that both classes must see the definitions of each other. Is it possible to break the circular dependency and still keep the definitions separated?

Comment: Some people use an inline file `inner.inl` and include the the file directly in `Outer`'s class definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The best you can do is store a pointer (or perhaps reference) to the inner class instead, which allows `Inner` to be incomplete. This is generally known as the `pImpl` idiom.

Comment: I would use std::unique_ptr<Inner> to implement pImpl idiom

Comment: Yes, that would be a good choice. You need a smart pointer that allows for an incomplete type. You have to be careful with the constructor and destructor of `Outer` - they can't be inline.